# C# sudden DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm working with a selfmade C++ DLL for a while. Methods of the DLL are called in a C# project. Everything worked just fine! After I started the project today I get a System.DllNotFound exception. I don't know why... 
Code of the include:

```
[DllImport(@"D:\abc\xyz\zyx\x64\Debug\Controll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public static extern int startBLEScan();
```

Output while compiling the C++ Dll:

```
1>Controll.vcxproj -> D:\abc\xyz\zyx\x64\Debug\Controll.dll
1>Done building project "Controll.vcxproj".
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

As you an see, the path is the same. 
I don't know what causes this error, since i haven't changed the code in any way and this error never occured before...

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Full Error Message:

```
System.DllNotFoundException
HResult=0x80131524
Message=The DLL "D:\abc\xyz\zyx\x64\Debug\Controll.dll": The given Module couldn't be found. (Exeption HRESULT: 0x8007007E) could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Virus scanner ?

Comment: No, i don't have a virus-scanner installed.

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Included in the edit

Comment: "The given module" does not necessarily refer to Controll.dll, it can also be a DLL that Controll.dll needs to get its job done.  Enable loader snaps or use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see more.